# How to find the square of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

What are the steps in solving for the question:

> For $i^2 = –1$, what is $(4 + i)^2$

The answer I was given was $15+8i$ but I'm unsure how this was the answer and what steps were taken to get there. Thank you.

Comment: It's the correct answer. Just develop by the binomial formula, taking into account $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Simply expand:
$$
(4+i)^2=(4+i)(4+i)=16+8i+i^2=15+8i.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
  (4+i)^2 &=
  (4+i)(4+i) \\&=
  16 +4i +4i + i^2 \\&=
  16 + 8i + (-1) \\&=
  15 + 8i
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the square $(4+i)^2=4^2+2\cdot 4i + i^2$